# How to implement IDataErrorInfo with lambda versions of RaisePropertyChanged in MVVM Light?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

Earlier I had:

```
const string FooPropertyName = "Foo";
```

And I was doing:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(FooPropertyName);
```

I was also implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` interface like this:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        switch(columnName)
        {
            case FooPropertyName:
                return CheckFoo();

            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that I want to switch to the lambda syntax and omit the string constant,

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo);
```

how can I implement `IDataErrorInfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the property name in a similar fashion

```
protected string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    var memberExpr = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpr == null) throw new ArgumentException("propertyExpression should represent access to a member");
    return memberExpr.Member.Name;
}
```

Then use it like this

```
if (columnName == GetPropertyName<MyClass>(() => Foo)) 
    return CheckFoo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used MVVM Light before, so this is more for informative purposes than for an answer, but I do know that in order to *not* supply a property name to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event, you would need to use the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx). According to the linked page, this

> Allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method

However, this attribute was only added in .NET 4.5, so if you're not using this version, then you won't be able to make use of it.

It should be used before the input parameter that you want to automatically supply the member name to... in your case, in the `RaisePropertyChanged` method:

```
public override void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The question asked how to implement `IDataErrorInfo` - your answer doesn't address that at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AdiLester, but if you had read my 'answer' as you call it, then you would have seen that it was actually *not* attempting to answer the question, but instead just used to provide some relevant information. I feel that it is somewhat ironic that you would take the time to make such a comment on my answer despite the fact that you didn't mention the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in your answer either... but you *are* attempting to answer the question, so *you* are the one that should have addressed it.

Comment: My answer demonstrates what needs to be done inside the `IDataErrorInfo` implementation. It doesn't require the word "IDataErrorInfo" to answer what is being asked.

Comment: My information demonstrates the use of the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` class... it also doesn't require the word `IDataErrorInfo` to do this.